# Ubuntu 18.04.3 XWayland crash

Tags: xorg, gnome-shell, crash

I have a new Dell G5-5590 laptop that generates XWayalnd crahes at least one time per day during the log off or returning from suspension (I'm running Xorg as I have Nvidia card).
Checking journalctl it seems like XWayland process gets unresponsive and it has to kill it:

```
ene 27 09:52:02 vanburen07-G5-5590 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3619]: #8
0x7ffc94b33a60 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82
(0x7fd0cdeb5de0 @ 71) ene 27 09:52:02 vanburen07-G5-5590
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3619]: #9 0x55ba36d51210 i  
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/statusNotifierWatcher.js:170
(0x7fd0947dc6f8 @ 68) ene 27 09:52:02 vanburen07-G5-5590
rg.gnome.Shell.desktop[3619]: #10 0x7ffc94b34650 I  
resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fd0cdeb5de0 @ 71)
ene 27 09:52:02 vanburen07-G5-5590 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3619]: #11
0x7ffc94b346f0 I   self-hosted:918 (0x7fd0cdef12b8 @ 394) ene 27
09:52:04 vanburen07-G5-5590 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3257]: (EE) ene 27
09:52:04 vanburen07-G5-5590 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3257]: Fatal
server error: ene 27 09:52:04 vanburen07-G5-5590
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3257]: (EE) failed to read Wayland events:
Broken pipe ene 27 09:52:04 vanburen07-G5-5590
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3257]: (EE) ene 27 09:52:04 vanburen07-G5-5590
gnome-session[3251]: gnome-session-binary[3251]: WARNING: Application
'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 11 ene 27 09:52:04
vanburen07-G5-5590 gnome-session-binary[3251]: Unrecoverable failure
in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop ene 27 09:52:04
vanburen07-G5-5590 gnome-session-binary[3251]: WARNING: Application
'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 11 ene 27 09:52:05
vanburen07-G5-5590 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4461]: glamor: EGL version
1.4: ene 27 09:52:06 vanburen07-G5-5590 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4461]: current session already has an ibus-daemon. ene 27 09:52:44
vanburen07-G5-5590 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4767]: == Stack trace for
context 0x563051634340 ==
```

I've tried to disable all the extensions but it doesn't seem like any of them creates a problem as the issue repeats even with all the extensions turned off.
I've tried to return back to an older Timeshift snap I had before the issues started appearing in case I messed something up but that didn't help either.
Tried to update Nvidia driver from 430 to 435 and that didn't resolve it as well.
This is not a big issue because it the worst case it creates a freeze of like 5 - 10 seconds when I log off and even shorter in case if it crashes returning from suspend mode but it generates .crash file and it's a little annoying.

I've tried to Google the problem but haven't found anything matching the problem exactly.

Comment: Yes I mean 18.04.3 - that was a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the answer, apparently Ubuntu runs Wayland for the login screen or starts XWayland process in case you want to switch to Wayland from Xorg during the login.
My Nvidia card (or its specific driver version) doesn't work fine with Wayland - if I login into Wayland it wull show VGA as Intel (the build-in one) and HDMDI, for eample, will not work as it's controled by the Nvidia card. That was crashing XWayland process sometimes when login screen was drawed - dugin the log off or returning from the suspend mode in particular.

Editing /etc/gdm3/custom.conf uncommenting WaylandEnable=false as suggested in the same document: # Uncoment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
forces the login screen to use Xorg.

I cannot login into Wayland anymore but it was no use to me since Nvidia card wasn't working fine anyways (I need  HDMI to share the laptop screen from time to time) and it's easthier for me to "switch off" Wayland as I haven't used it in any case the troubleshoot Nvidia/Wayland compatibility which can be rather difficult/time consuming if possible at all